# How to pass parcelable variable values using intent in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, badparcelableexception

I am getting BadParcelableException in my application on passing parcelable values using intent action. How to pass parcelable values and retrieve them in another classes?

Below is my code:

```
public MySample mySample;

  public class MySample implements Parcelable {
        private boolean galleryPicker = false;
        private boolean gallery = false;
        private ImageButton button;
        private View view;

        public ImageButton getButton() {
            return button;
        }

        public void setPostButtonItem(ImageButton button) {
            this.button= button;
        }
        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeStringArray(new String[] {});
        }

        public int describeContents(){
            return 0;
        }
```

Intent action:

```
public class Popup// (Actually I call this class from my BaseActivity)
{
    public Popup(Activity activity,ActionBar action)
    {
        MySample mySample= new MySample();
        sample.data.setStatus=true;
        no= (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.no);
        yes= (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.yes);
        mySample.gallery = true;
        mySample.count = true;
        context = getContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("sample", mySample);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Extract intent in another class:

```
private MySample mySample;
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
this.mySample= data.getParcelable("sample");
```

Exception:

> Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class

Comment: Your problem is not in passing the value. Your problem is that you did not fully implement `Parcelable`. In particular, quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html): "Classes implementing the Parcelable interface must also have a static field called CREATOR, which is an object implementing the Parcelable.Creator interface. "

Comment: let me try it and can you wait for my response

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 public class MySample implements Parcelable {

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public MySample createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MySample(in);
        }

        public MySample[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MySample[size];
        }
    };
    private boolean galleryPicker = false;
    private boolean gallery = false;

    public MySample(Parcel in) {
        boolean[] temp = new boolean[2];
        in.readBooleanArray(temp);
        galleryPicker = temp[0];
        gallery = temp[1];
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeBooleanArray(new boolean[]{galleryPicker, gallery});
    }
}
```

Comment: i will let you know, can you wait for my response

Comment: i have to pass string value along with this

Comment: Yeah, Sure i can wait!.

Comment: along with the boolean have to send by static values like for text,layout,imagebutton

Comment: Then, what dou you want to do? Explain yourself.

Comment: i am using getter and setter for textview, layout and buttons, boolean. i have a parcelable inner class in which i can't declare public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR as static

Comment: I´m not sure you can send these objects inside the parcelable object, look at this example [link](http://www.easyinfogeek.com/2014/01/android-tutorial-two-methods-of-passing.html)

Comment: can u plz give sample example for serlizable